# how to solve android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_paper_plane.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02008f?

Tags: android, vector

I know this question is asking many time but i tried all of that but nothing meet my requirement i used  `android:drawableLeft` attribute in XML file for showing vector image in my button and its running on above API 21 but if i am running on same code in below API 21 like 19 then app got crashed, i am already add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` , and `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` but both not work for me can any one help me out of this,my xml code is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
      android:id="@+id/shduleSms"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_shedule_sms"
      android:drawablePadding="5dip"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textConCount"
      android:padding="15dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/textConCount"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:text="@string/sendlater"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:theme="@style/MyButtonTwo"
      />
```

Comment: can you put your gradle code here

Comment: Please share the code of ic_shedule_sms file if is vector.

EDIT: You have used ic_shedule_sms as drawableLeft but the error says ic_paper_plane. Is the error related to this 'shduleSms' element?

Comment: yes this this is same element i have two button on that i put second element code here

Answer (score 0):

Please share your drawable code. There are some properties that cannot be used below SDK version 21 in vector drawable files and might lead to runtime crashes.

Comment: <vector android:height="20dp" android:viewportHeight="60.064"
    android:viewportWidth="60.064" android:width="20dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

Comment: <path android:fillColor="#FFFFFF" android:pathData="M59.84,7.9c-0.22,-0.27 -0.56,-0.39 -0.89,-0.35c-0.08,0 -0.15,0.02 -0.22,0.04L0.74,23.35C0.31,23.47 0.01,23.85 0,24.29c-0.01,0.44 0.27,0.84 0.69,0.98l21.22,6.95l-1.9,15.18c-0.05,0.4 0.14,0.79 0.49,0.99c0.16,0.09 0.33,0.13 0.5,0.13c0.22,0 0.43,-0.07 0.61,-0.21l7.76,-5.95l6.81,9.73c0.19,0.27 0.49,0.43 0.82,0.43c0.02,0 0.05,-0 0.07,-0c0.35,-0.02 0.66,-0.23 0.82,-0.54l22.06,-43C60.13,8.63 60.09,8.2 59.84,7.9zM52.9,11.24L22.86,30.43L4.48,24.41L52.9,11.24zM22.29,45.28l1.38,-11.05l4.55,6.51L22.29,45.28zM36.87,49.59L24.42,31.81l32.1,-20.51L36.87,49.59

Answer (score 0):

This error mostly occurrs due to a corrupt or unknown file. Please share your drawable source code if using an xml(vector).

Comment: its working fine api 21 so is there any issue in api 19.